# missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Tags: python, django, model, django-admin

I am attempting to update an extended user model `profile` in admin.py actions. I have been researching this for a couple hours now and have come up short. I am receiving a `pc_add_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'` error, please help.

```
class ProfileAdminInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile


class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
                    'rewards_punch_card', 'rewards_tier', 'credits']
    list_select_related = True
    inlines = [ProfileAdminInLine]

    actions = ['pc_add_1', 'pc_add_2', 'pc_add_3', 'pc_add_4', 'pc_add_5',
               'pc_add_6', 'pc_add_7', 'pc_add_8', 'pc_add_9']

    def rewards_tier(self, user):
        return user.profile.rewards_tier

    def rewards_punch_card(self, user):
        return user.profile.rewards_current

    def pc_add_1(self, request, user, queryset):

        punch_card = user.profile.rewards_current
        tier = user.profile.rewards_tier
        credits = user.profile.rewards_credits

        punch_cards_updated = queryset.update(punch_card + 1)

        if punch_cards_updated == 10:
            queryset.update(punch_card == 0)
            if tier == 1:
                queryset.update(tier + 1)
                queryset.update(credits + 25)
            elif tier == 2:
                queryset.update(tier + 1)
                queryset.update(credits + 35)
            elif tier == 3:
                queryset.update(tier + 1)
                queryset.update(credits + 45)
            elif tier == 4:
                queryset.update(tier + 1)
                queryset.update(credits + 55)
            elif tier == 5:
                queryset.update(credits + 65)
            elif tier == 6:
                queryset.update(credits + 65)

        else:
            pass
```

traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/auth/user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1569, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1305, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
TypeError: pc_add_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'
[13/Nov/2016 15:16:52] "POST /admin/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 106710
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: updated, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the method signature wrong:

```
def pc_add_1(self, request, user, queryset):
```

For admin actions it should be

```
def pc_add_1(self, request, queryset):
```

now if you want to know which admin user is making the change you can find that out from `request.user`

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the argument `user` from the line

```
def pc_add_1(self, request, user, queryset):
```

Django will call that method with `request` and `queryset` only. You will be able to get the user with `request.user`.